# React Native with Typescript and Jest is broken after 0.57 Update: Couldn't find preset "module:metro-react-native-babel-preset" relative to directory

Tags: typescript, react-native, babeljs, jestjs, enzyme

If you integrate test with Jest and Enzyme in the new React Version 0.57 and TypeScript, they won't work. Here are the steps to reproduce:

Create a new React Native project:

```
react-native init MyApp -package "com.my.app" --template typescript && node MyApp/setup.js
```

Install all Jest and Enzyne related packages:

```
npm install --save-dev react-dom enzyme enzyme-react-adapter-16 jest-fetch-mock ts-jest
```

Add the jest configuration:

```
"jest": {
  "preset": "react-native",
  "moduleFileExtensions": [
    "ts",
    "tsx",
    "js"
  ],
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.(js)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
    "\\.(ts|tsx)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/ts-jest/preprocessor.js"
  },
  "testRegex": "(/__tests__/.*|\\.(test|spec))\\.(ts|tsx|js)$",
  "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
    "\\.snap$",
    "<rootDir>/node_modules/"
  ],
  "cacheDirectory": ".jest/cache",
  "setupFiles": [
    "./tests/setup.js"
  ]
}
```

Add a file `tests/setup.js` and include the following configuration:

```
import Enzyme from "enzyme";
import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16";
import { NativeModules } from "react-native";

global.fetch = require("jest-fetch-mock"); // eslint-disable-line no-undef
jest.mock("react-native-config");
Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
```

Last but not least add a basic test (App.test.tsx) to check if Jest and Enzyme work:

```
import React from "react";
import { shallow } from "enzyme";
import { View } from "react-native";
import App from "./App";

const createTestProps = props => ({
  ...props
});

describe("App", () => {
  describe("rendering", () => {
    let wrapper;
    let props;
    beforeEach(() => {
      props = createTestProps({});
      wrapper = shallow(<App {...props} />);
    });

    it("should render a <View />", () => {
      expect(wrapper.find(View)).toHaveLength(1);
    });
  });
});
```

If you now try to run the test, the error message you get is:

```
 FAIL  app/App.test.tsx
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Couldn't find preset "module:metro-react-native-babel-preset" relative to directory "<Directory"
```

### Edit

It seems like this has something to do with Babel.

Comment: For anyone who finds this trying to resolve `Unexpected import...` errors when using `react-test-renderer`, the Medium article in the accepted answer is the only solution that got my tests running.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I found the answer here in this issue: https://github.com/facebook/metro/issues/242#issuecomment-421139247

Basically, add this to your Jest section in `package.json`:

```
"transform": { "^.+\\.js$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/react-native/jest/preprocessor.js" }
```

Comment: Awesome! This solution did it for me

Comment: I wasn't looking for a solution for TypeScript, but this fixed the same error message on my standard Jest testing. Thanks!

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you!

Comment: Thanks a lot bro.. you saved my day!

Comment: This is deprecated in versions of more than 0.61.x. If you write this line tests will be broken in them. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56814268/how-to-mock-a-third-party-react-native-component-with-jest

Answer (score 6):

had a similar issue when upgrading to 0.57, my `package.json` still contained an entry for `babel-preset-react-native` (which is now deprecated in favor of `metro-react-native-babel-preset`). All I had to do was

`yarn remove babel-preset-react-native`

and then

`yarn add metro-react-native-babel-preset --dev`

Lastly, make sure you change your `.babelrc` from

```
{
  "presets": ["react-native"]
}
```

to

```
{
  "presets": ["module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"]
}
```

More info can be found [here](https://github.com/facebook/metro/tree/master/packages/metro-react-native-babel-preset)

Comment: Thank you for sharing! I also found a way to solve this keeping `"react-native"` as the preset setting.

Answer (score 0):

If I use `"presets": ["react-native"]` then production/development is broken but tests are working.

If I use `"presets": ["module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"]` then tests are broken but production/development is working.

Not sure why it's like that but a .babelrc solution for me like below works both for development/production and tests. Just add env parameter to your .babelrc file.

```
"env": {
    "test": {
        "presets": ["react-native"]
    },
    "production": {
        "presets": ["module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"]
    },
    "development": {
        "presets": ["module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"]
    }
}
```