# Ran all test suites matching /e2e/i with tests matching "^((?!:ios:).)*$"

Tags: react-native, jestjs, detox

I am doing Detox testing and matching takes default as ios and I want to test in android, I am not able to change it to android. help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Detox isn't running an iOS test. It only looks like that because of the [negative lookahead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12210820/5508175) in the regex.

```--testNamePattern='^((?!:ios:).)*$'`

> It's a negative lookahead, which means that for the 
>   expression to match, the part within (?!...) must not match

**update to comment**

Currently there is an issue in `react-native:0.57.8` that is causing the the following error:

`Error: Couldn't find preset "module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"`

There is currently a workaround that can be found here https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/21241#issuecomment-431464191

#### Step 1

Create babel.config.js with the following content (basically equivalent to stock .babelrc)

```
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true)

  return {
    presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset']
  }
}
```

#### Step 2

Remove .babelrc

#### Step 3

Run yarn add --dev babel-jest babel-core@^7.0.0-bridge.0 @babel/core

Personally I haven't needed to do step 3.

Comment: Thank you, which means we no need to worry about this. I am getting this error how to resolve it "Couldn't find preset "module:metro-react-native-babel-preset" relative to directory". I have did https://stackoverflow.com/a/52347785/10031919 this still it showing this issue

Comment: Thank you, I have this issue could you help to resolve issue. "Error: Error: No views in hierarchy found matching detox", While navigating from one screen to other screen I am getting this error, I am not able to find next screen elements because of this issue

Comment: I would suggest asking a new question on stackoverflow. There you can post the error message in full and what you have tried to resolve it.